# Two arrays in two columns of a table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I currently have two separate table bodies like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cup in cups" >
     <td>{{::cup.type}}</td> 
     <td>{{::cup.name}}</td> 
     <td>{{::cup.id}}</td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="holder in holders" >
     <td>{{::holder.type}}</td> 
     <td>{{::holder.name}}</td> 
     <td>{{::holder.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

How can I combine them into one table, so that the columns are pulled from either the holders or cups array? Something like this (I know you cannot simply ng-repeat both arrays):

```
<tr ng-repeat="cup in cups" ng-repeat="holder in holders" >
     <td>{{::cup.type}}</td>
     <td>{{::holder.type}}</td> 
     <td>{{::cup.name}}</td> 
     <td>{{::holder.name}}</td> 
     <td>{{::cup.id}}</td>
     <td>{{::holder.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are the arrays always the same length?

Comment: don't you could simply merge the 2 arrays, then repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your arrays would always be equal in regard to index, so you can use the index of the `ng-repeat` directive:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cup in cups">
     <td>{{::cup.type}}</td>
     <td>{{::holders[$index].type}}</td> 
     <td>{{::cup.name}}</td> 
     <td>{{::holders[$index].name}}</td> 
     <td>{{::cup.id}}</td>
     <td>{{::holders[$index].id}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yep that was it. I was also completely butchering format when I had tried that before, and had holders[$index].id as opposed to the other way around. Wouldn't make sense in retrospect. Thanks for the help!